# What are some good resources on flocking and swarm algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, boids

Awhile ago I read the novel [Prey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0066214122). Even though it is definitely in the realm of fun science fiction, it piqued my interest in swarm/flock AI.   I've been seeing some examples of these demos recently on reddit such as the [Nvidia plane flocking video](http://chrisbenjaminsen.com/stuff/boidsas3.swf) and [Chris Benjaminsen's flocking sandbox](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/a3qky/just_for_you_reddit_a_flocking_sandbox_in_flash/) ([source](http://chrisbenjaminsen.com/stuff/boidsas3.zip)).

I'm interested in writing some simulation demos involving swarm or flocking AI. I've taken Artificial Intelligence in college but we never approached the subject of simulating swarming/flocking behaviors and a quick flip through my textbook reveals that it isn't dicussed.

[image]
<sub>Flocking Sandbox</sub>

What are some solid resources for learning some of the finer points around flock/swarm algorithms?  Does anyone have any experience in this field so they could point me in the right direction concerning a well suited AI book or published papers?

Answer (score 10):

What you're asking for is actually much more simple than you think. The canonical source is http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/.

Answer (score 3):

there are a few techniques that you may want to read up on:

1. [Ant Colony Optmiziation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization)
2. [Celluar Automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)
3. [Self Organizing Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map)

Also: [The wiki page isn't a bad start.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence)